# Is it possible to implement a binary heap that is both a max and a min heap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, binary-heap

I'm trying to implement a binary heap (priority queue) that has the capabilities of both a min heap and a max heap. It needs to have an `insert(value)`, `extractMin()`, and an `extractMax()` method. The extract methods remove the value from the heap and return the value.

I was originally using two arrays, called `minHeap` and `maxHeap`, one to store the data in a min heap structure, and the other to store the same data in a max heap structure. So when I call `extractMin()`, it removes and returns the value from `minHeap`. Then I have to remove that value from `maxHeap` as well (and vice-versa if I called `extractMax()`) in order to keep the data set identical in both heaps. And because of the heap-order property, it's guaranteed that I'll find that value in the leaves of the other heap. Searching for that value in the other heap results in a time complexity of O(n) or more precisely, O(n/2) since I'll only be searching the leaves. Not to mention, the `percolatingDown()` and `percolatingUp()` methods to restore the heaps after removing values is already O(log n); so in total, the extract methods would be O(n). The problem is, I need the extract methods to be O(log n).

Is there a better way to go about this?

I also thought of this idea but wanted to know what you all think first.

I just finished coding a "median heap" by placing the smaller half of the data in the max heap and the larger half in the min heap. With that structure, I'm able to easily retrieve the median of a given set of values. And I was thinking of using a similar structure of placing the smaller half of the data in the min heap and the larger half in the max heap and using the mean (rather than the median) of all the values to be the deciding factor of whether to place the value in the max or min heap when calling `insert(value)`. I think this might work as the extract methods would stay O(log n).

Comment: Why not use a binary tree instead? The `extract` methods would still be `O(log n)` as it is simply the left-most and right-most node for `extractMin()` and `extractMax()` respectively.

Comment: @M.Shaw I could do that, but this is an assignment and my prof wants a heap.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark, why your extract method takes `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: How about a max heap with a pointer to the min leaf?

Comment: @Beta You would need to search for the new min leaf everytime the previous min leaf is removed anyways .

Comment: @Ghost_Stark Shouldn't it be `O(logn) + O(n) = O(n)`?

Comment: @EricZ Ha you're right. Not sure what I was thinking. Let me fix the post.

Comment: If you look for _what_ you want (as opposed to _how_ to achieve your current goal (cf. [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))), you find [double-ended priority queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue#Interval_heaps) and _interval heaps_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way is to just use a binary search tree, as M. Shaw recommends.

If you're required to build this on top of binary heaps, then in each heap, alongside each element, store the element's position in the other heap. Every time you move an element in one heap, you can go straight to its position in the other heap and update it. When you perform a delete-min or delete-max, no expensive linear scan in the other heap is required.

For example, if you store `std::pair`s with `first` as the element value and `second` as the position in the other heap, swapping two elements in the min-heap while updating their counterparts in the max-heap might look like this:

```
swap(minheap[i], minheap[j]);
maxheap[minheap[i].second].second = i;
maxheap[minheap[j].second].second = j;
```

Comment: This will work, but I'm not familiar with this `pair` capability. Would it be easier to just use a struct that has a `minHeapIndex`, `maxHeapIndex`, and a `value` member for each element?

Comment: @Ghost_Stark: I don't know if it'd be easier, but you could certainly do that.

Comment: @user2357112 "`alongside each element, store the element's position in the other heap`" -- Just a small problem. When the first heap is created, how to store in `the other heap` when the second heap doesn't even exist? A standlone structure is required. E.g., a hash table indexed by the element key. The hashed value can be a struct comprised of positions in two heaps.

Comment: @EricZ: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Why wouldn't the other heap exist? You'd create both heaps before trying to insert anything. Also, the grouping goes `store the element's (position in the other heap)`, not `(store the element's position) in the other heap`, in case that was unclear.

Comment: @user2357112. E.g., you create minHeap first, and then maxHeap. When you create minHeap, e.g., for element `A` whose array index is `3`, you need store index `3` in the element `A'` in maxHeap, right? But at that time maxHeap isn't there.

Comment: @EricZ: Are you assuming we would *populate* one entire heap before initializing the other? The way I'm imagining it, we initialize two empty heaps and perform insertions on them together.

Comment: @user2357112 That's exactly how I'm doing it. And even if I wanted to populate an entire heap with a given set of data, I can still perform insertion one at a time in linear fashion to populate both heaps simultaneously.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, that incremental build should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a hash table for the heap elements, which is shared by two heaps. The table is indexed by the value of the heap element. The value of the hashed bucket can be a struct consisting of the array index in minHeap and maxHeap respectively.

The benefit of this approach is that it is non-intrusive, meaning that the structure of the heap elements remains the same. And you don't have to create heaps side-by-side. You can create one after the other with the usual heap creation precedure.

E.g.,

```
struct tIndex
{
   // Array index of the element in two heaps respectively
   size_t minIndex;
   size_t maxIndex;
};

std::unordered_map<int, tIndex> m;
```

[image]

Pay attention that any change to the heap may change the underlying array index of existing elements. So when you add/remove an element, or swap two elements, you may need to update its array index in the hash table accordingly.

Comment: I like this. I appreciate the pictures too, very helpful. But I think I'll stick with the above answer for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. The trick is to use another level of indirection. Keep the keys in an array K[i] and store only indices i in the heaps.  Also keep two reverse maps: one for the max heap and one for the min. A reverse map is an array of integers R such that R[i] is the location in the min (or max) heap of the index i for key K[i].  In other words, if M[j] is the min (or max) heap, then R[M[j]] = j;  Now whenever you do a sifting operation to move elements around in a heap, you must update the respective reverse map at the same time. In fact it works just like the relation above. At every step where you change a heap element M[j] = z, also update the reverse map R[z] = j; This increases run time by only a small constant factor. Now to delete K[i] from the heap, you can find it in constant time: It's at M[R[i]]. Sift it up to the root and remove it.

I know this works (finding a heap object to delete in constant time) because I've implemented it as part of a bigger algorithm.  Check out https://github.com/gene-ressler/lulu/blob/master/ext/lulu/pq.c .  The larger algorithm is for map marker merging: https://github.com/gene-ressler/lulu/wiki

Comment: This is a bit confusing for me maybe because of all the K's, R's, M's, i's, j's, and z's. I need to think this through ha. It also seems very memory intensive. Two heaps, one array to store indices, and two reverse maps. Not sure if this is something my prof would want.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-data-structure-question/

Min-Max heap I would say is the answer as pointed by "user2357112" if the most frequent operation is  findMin and findMax.  BST might be an overkill if we dont really want a completely ordered data structure , the above is a partial ordered data structured. Refer the link posted above.